# Symfony (PHP framework) and MongoDB ( or any json-based database)

Tags: php, json, symfony1, mongodb

I was wondering if its possible to use a json-based schema-free, document-based database like Mongodb or Couchdb on a symfony project like its used for ruby-on-rails websites? And if yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 7):

There is a [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](http://github.com/avalanche123/DoctrineMongoDBBundle) for use with Symfony 2

Answer (score 6):

You might get some help from the [MongoDB PHP Language Center](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center). There are links to several PHP libraries for MongoDB, including a centralized logger for symfony applications.

Answer (score 4):

You can also check out http://li3.me/, the only full-stack PHP framework with fully-integrated support for MongoDB (and CouchDB).

Comment: Looks interesting but another framework :(

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only framework to have integrated Mongo support as of yet is [Vork](http://www.Vork.us).

I saw a post from someone who retrofitted Cake to use MongoDB, but they basically had to rewire the whole model-engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try building your project with the no-orm flag. There is little need to have an object relational database if you are not using a relational database. Just build classes for your data in PHP. These will function as your schema, which makes sense sense as a schema is not defined at the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

All the majore modern framework can work with Mongodb.
Symfony do it very well with doctrine as an exemple